# how to set validator in formArary like formGroup?

Tags: angular7

I have created a form using form array, and i want to set and clear the validation based on selecting particular value from dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

formArrayName.at(ind).setValidators([Validators.required]);
 formArrayName.at(ind).updateValueAndValidity();

formArrayName: is the form name.
ind: is the index of the particular filed, on which u want to apply the validation.
updateValueAndValidity: it is required, sometimes setValidators is reflecting, so